# Ajax character encoding changed after send to server

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, character-encoding

I have an ajax like this:

```
          $.ajax('../EditUser?userId=' + editingId + '&full_name=' + name + '&position=' + position + '&office=' + office
            + '&office_address=' + office_address + '&age=' + age + '&user_login_name=' + user_login_name + '&email=' + email
            + '&user_type=' + usertype + '&password=' + password + '&meetingIds=' + selectedmeetingid, {
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.indexOf('error://') < 0) {
                        $('#tbl_meetings').html(data);
                    } else {
                        $('#errorMessage').html(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error " + errorThrown);
                    alert("error " + textStatus);
                    alert("error " + jqXHR.status);
                }
            }
        );
```

and my server received data with wrong encoding,example: "Hà Thị Minh Thắng" became "H? Th? Minh Th?ng" after received on server side.I tried adding

```
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15",
```

and

```
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
    jqXHR.overrideMimeType('text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
}
```

to my ajax but it didn't works. So, anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I don't see any `data:objectHere` being sent. You are using a get URL on a post.

Comment: Post an object in the body of the request (not in the url) - e.g. `var data = { userId: editingId, full_name: name, .... }` and in the ajax, use `url: '@Url.Action("EditUser")',` and `data: data`, and your POST metod will have a parameter for a model containing those properties. But of course if you have generated you view correctly then it would be just `data: $('form').serialize(),`

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke : Thanks for well detailed explaination , that's working

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying content type to the ajax request & you have to add header to the server side to receive the charset.

```
    $.ajax({
        data: parameters,
        type: "POST",
        url: your-url,
        timeout: 20000,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: callback
    });

    // Server Side... (This is an example in php which I have used in my app)
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

Hope this helps you!